# Redirect folder and its contents to (no folder) while keeping www and https

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect

I have three websites. Each is a folder and accessible like:

```
example.com/siteA
example.com/siteB
example.com/siteC
```

A category and product may exist in those sites like:

```
example.com/siteA/category/subcategory/productABC
```

I have 3 new urls, under 2 domains.

```
siteA = https://www.newsiteA.com
siteB = https://www.newsiteB.com
siteC = https://www.newsiteB.com/siteC
```

The problem is redirecting the old urls and their contents, to the new url while also redirecting with www and https. I cannot get them to all work together.

An example of a desired redirect:

```
http://example.com/siteA/categoryA/*contents*
to
https://www.newsiteA.com/categoryB/*contents*
```

*contents* being anything after that url.
I've been trying via htaccess (of a magento site) but dont mind doing it via another method.
Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: How exactly do you figure out what categoryB should be? Is there a categoryA->categoryB mapping or something?

Comment: I would write the names of the real categories for each rewrite. I dont expect it to be a one size fits all. For some categories, they were 1 category but are 2 now. Or the names changed on the categories. So the idea is to map those, but keep the product name (always the same), and also always use www and https

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules as very first rules in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^siteA(/.*)?$ https://www.newsiteA.com/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]

RewriteRule ^siteB(/.*)?$ https://www.newsiteB.com/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]

RewriteRule ^siteC(/.*)?$ https://www.newsiteC.com/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```